# Dynamic timeline spreadsheet with selective stickiness?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to create my first spreadsheet ever, but there's one function that I'm finding very difficult to find guidance for from the internet, just like the title of this post felt a bit clumsy to phrase.

In column A, I have established the following logic to go on [for the next 2 months since today]:

- Today
- What's above +1 day
- What's above +1 day
- etc.

So you have an auto-updating dynamic timeline where there's no "hard data".
What if for other columns, I wanted to store user input data that would stick to the *specific date* on its level at the time of creating it, instead of [+n days from today], so that it could migrate upwards in the cells of the user input column as the date is nearing? Just like a calendar that doesn't have a past, but the events move with the date.

I'm using LibreOffice to familiarize with the spreadsheet idea, but as far as I understood, it uses the same syntax as Excel so any help that you could give needn't be application-specific.

EDIT: Screenshot added for illustrative purposes.

[image: Screenshot for illustrative purposes]

Comment: @BruceWayne yup, that's what I already have and it works fine. Please read my post again, what I'm trying to figure out is explained right after the bullet list.

Comment: D'oh, sorry. I'll reread.

Comment: Do you want data past a certain age to drop off from the entire spreadsheet, or just the visible portion?

Comment: @music2myear As described, the date range visible is "from today to 2 months in the future", no yesterdays, no past of any kind.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but I wasn't sure what you wanted to happen to the data entered for now-no-longer-visible days. If this is only for viewing the data, then you can delete the row-dates that are no longer visible, but if you're hoping to run analysis, averages, or anything else it could be very helpful to keep that data around, even if it is no longer visible in the main portion of the sheet.

Comment: I think the focus is going astray here; I know I could make a hard date calendar but I have plenty of them already and that's not what I need. I need to see a dynamic [today until 2 months after] regardless of what time of the year it is, and no leftovers of the past, no need to delete anything, only add, and let them drift into oblivion as time goes by. Hang on, I'll update the post with a screenshot to visualize.

Comment: This will require macros, because each entry must be moved to follow its associated date.  Are you willing to learn to write LibreOffice Basic or Excel VBA?  The code required will be completely different for each Office suite.

Comment: @JimK Oh I see. I think LibreOffice it is – since this isn't for commercial purposes, I'm hesitating to buy software for this odd instance when there's free software available. My only scripting experience is with Applescript, so I have an idea of computer logic but not of what one would call serious coding. I'll take a while to process that material and see what I can make of it, thanks. Will report back.

Comment: This can be done with normal formulas or using macros. However, what problem are you trying to solve as both methods seems more complicated than what a starting spreadsheet should need to use.

Comment: @bvaughn What approach would you use for achieving this?

Comment: I would separate the data from the display. I would have a Data table that included a column for the date on a different sheet. Then on the sheet you are doing, I would use either vlookup or index/match. Of the two, vlookup is easier to understand. For Vlookup to work, the left hand column has the date. For each cell it looks up the date, if found display info, if not found then blank. The cells would look similar to  =iferror(Vlookup(DateValue,MyDataTable,Mycolumn,false),"") where actual cell references or names replace the MY things.

Comment: +1 for separating data from display. You *always* want to separate raw data, data "massaging", and data display.

Comment: Okay, I made a different place for the 'comments', where they'd have their dates hardcoded. I'm learning to use VLOOKUP and it works. UNTIL: From row 17 onwards, the cells will just get populated by (whatever is above) for no good reason. I looked it up and found it out to be "a typical floating point problem which starts from 16-18 rows onwards". Seriously? To be honest, I expected spreadsheets to be better than that, taken how popular they are. To have a title row + rows for each day for 2 months, my document has 64 rows. Not being able to handle it beyond 17 is unbelievably primitive.